# how to get number of hours between two Java.time.LocalTime instances

Tags: java, time, java-8, java-time

I have a instance of `Java.Time.LocalTime` as startTime. After completion of a task I want to get the current time and get the difference of two in `hours`.

```
    int noOfHours = LocalTime.now() - startTime;
```

Comment: @Jens not sure why you removed the java tag...

Comment: @Jens but Java 8 is java!

Comment: @assylias but there is a special `java-8` tag so i think that should be used when i have a java8 question.

Comment: @Jens Adding java-8 makes sense but I think it's better to leave java as well : when we are on java 10, people won't necessarily use java-8 as a tag when looking for such questions. See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.HOURS;

HOURS.between(startTime, LocalTime.now());
```

Answer (score 2):

Two choices, both involving `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.HOURS`:

```
// use the until() method on LocalTime
long noOfHours = startTime.until(LocalTime.now(), ChronoUnit.HOURS);

// use the between() method on HOURS
long noOfHours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(startTime, LocalTime.now());
```

To convert `long` to `int` use `Math.toIntExact(noOfHours)`.